# Liquibase Single Precondition for multiple Changesets

Tags: liquibase

I have a number of changesets that I would like to run if a specific condition exists. For example run changesets 1, 2, and 3 only if sqlCheck executed with the excepted results.

I can copy the precondition into each changeset. However it feels like there should be a more efficient way of doing this. As the number of changesets grows, the files have a lot of these duplicates.

The preConditions element directly under databaseChangeLog seems to only configure dbms and runAs.

Is there a way to define a single preCondition that will be used by multiple change sets?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be good to share some specifics about your preconditions in order to get better answers. It may be that your ultimate goal is better met by a different workflow or some other liquibase feature.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible but sometimes you can avoid using preconditions when you declare a `property` tag instead. For example when you have preconditions for different databases like Oracle and SQL Server which have different data types like
 `number` in Oracle and `float` in SQL Server, you can instead of using a precondition for each database use a `property`tag:

```
<property dbms="oracle" name="DECIMALTYPE" value="NUMBER" />
<property dbms="mssql" name="DECIMALTYPE" value="FLOAT" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look into how properties work in liquibase and see if that can solve my problem. I have in the mean time resorted to copy the preCondition to each changeset